# How to change the prompt value of an RDLC report parameter in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, parameters, rdlc

I have upgraded my projects to VS2010 a while ago and i'm using local report server reports (RDLC).

The parameter definition dialogs have moved to the Report Data pane, that was the first barrier to get over.

Now i wonder where i can change the *prompt* value of a parameter - the text the user is prompted when entering a value for the parameter.

I know i can change it by editing the rdlc file in an xml editor - i just can't belief that they have removed the textbox from the dialog.

See a screenshot of the parameter properties window in VS2010:
[image]

Comment: alright, i did a little bit of research and found out on technet that vs2010 doesn't support report projects.  So, is this an embedded report on a web page?

Comment: Its a normal class library project which contains a few reports. YOu can add it with Project -> Add -> New Item -> Reporting -> Report

Answer (score 0):

Well,  apparently i don't have reporting services installed for vs2010, but i've got 2008, so hopefully it's in the same place.

In 2008, there is a window called Report Data that has your parameters, data sources, and data sets.  Your parameter/s should show up under the Parameters section.  If you right click a parameter and click parameter properties, a new window appears.  Under the General section there's a box titled Prompt.  I believe this is what you need to change.

Hope this works in VS2010.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Apparently its not there. I have clarified my question, because its 2010 specific. I know it was there in V2008. But where is it now?